# How to use regex in HandleBars.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

This is the first time I am working on `script type="text/x-handlebars"`. I have an object `{{this.pin}}` which returns me the `URL (https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png)`. What I want to do is grab that URL and get specific text.

Code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="MapDeliveryAddressTemplate">    
    <div class="map-delivery-addresses-pin" tabindex="0"><img src={{this.pin}} aria_label={{this.pin}}/></div>
</script>
```

Here, `{{this.pin}}` returns `https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png`.

What I want is:

1. Get only `A` from `markerA`
2. use that `A` to `aria_label`.

Desired result should be like this:

```
<div class="map-delivery-addresses-pin" tabindex="0"><img src={{this.pin}} aria_label="A"/></div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own [helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) in Handlebars to achieve this. Set up a function, let's call it parseMarker, to return your value. Your new template would look like this:

`<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="MapDeliveryAddressTemplate">

    <div class="map-delivery-addresses-pin" tabindex="0"><img src={{this.pin}} aria_label={{{parseMarker this.pin}}})/></div>
</script>`

Calls to helpers are delimited by triple braces and the gist of your helper function would just be to return the match you want from a regex.